# Placing FrameLayout in Coordinator Layout which acts as Fragment container

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is the XML of the activity which holds the fragment in FrameLayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/overview_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/action_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp" />


            <veeresh.droid.harmony.utilities.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:font_name="bold" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/action_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/primary_light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

When transaction is made, the contents of the current activity and the newly added framgent are overlapped. Where do I place the FrameLayout here?
How do I see only the contents of the newly added framgnet?

Comment: A drawer layou supports two children , trying adding the frame layout inside the coordinator layout.

Comment: Nope, still overlaps

Comment: Why do you need frame layout if you're working with view pager?

Comment: The viewpager holds only the high level fragments (like an overview), the details of each fragment is given to the above fragment

Comment: Add the frame layout inside the coordinator layout , add the view pager inside the frame layout. Remove the layout behaviour of view pager.

Comment: Still has the overlap

Answer (score 0):

Drawer layout contains only two childs first is for content and second is for drawer items.so your framelayout should be navigation drawer first element.
And if you want to use tablayout with viewpager then put your tablayout and viewpager code in seperate fragment and open it when your activity loads.

so your drawer layout xml should look like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <FrameLayout  //Replace that fragment that should contain tablayout and viewpager with this framelayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    //Layout that contains drawer items

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And in your fragment's xml put this code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/overview_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/action_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp" />


            <veeresh.droid.harmony.utilities.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:font_name="bold" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/action_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/primary_light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now all you have to do is replace this fragment with framelayout..Hope that helps you

Comment: why move tablayout with viewpager into the fragment?

Comment: this only complicates the existing problem